# Is it possible somehow to set defaul joins/relations for model in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So I have model `Alarms` which is associated with `Site` model and others... Is it possible somehow set that by default when are required `Alarm.findAll().then()` I didn’t need to specify which associated models I need? It is necessary because `Alarms` table are using in many different situations and some different apps but in my case I need only entries which has site.

Or may be somehow I can add default joins to the model?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I encounter situations like this, I would just make a module which returns a promise of the query (with joins). So, for example you could make an `alarm_util` module

```
exports.getAlarm = function() {
    return Alarms.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: Site,
            include: [{
                model: OtherModel
            }]
        }]
    });
};

module.exports = exports;
```

And use it anywhere in your code like

```
alarm_util.getAlarm().then(alarm => {
    // The rest of your logic here...
});
```